# Is it possible to prohibit certain symbols when distorting properties? / mangle

Tags: webpack, minify, uglifyjs

I get properties starting with _ and $ (_, $, _a, $a, ...), which leads to an error due to these characters [being reserved by Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/index.html?redirect=true#Private-property-names-essential).

Is there a way to ban certain characters? I didn't find anything about this in the [documentation](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)..

My Setup:

```
optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
            minify: TerserPlugin.uglifyJsMinify,
            terserOptions: {
                mangle: {
                    properties: {
                        regex: /^m_/
                    }
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary solution to the problem using the [nth_identifier](https://github.com/terser/terser#mangle-options) assignment (doesn't work with uglifyJsMinify)

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          mangle: {
            properties: {
              regex: /^m_/,
              nth_identifier,
            }
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  }
})
```

What my nth_identifier looks like: [gist.github.com/Andreslav](https://gist.github.com/Andreslav/7f31d37b9f682e7b4f491f6b7de21900)